# PHP script stops after warning appears

Tags: php, iis

Previously I had `PHP 7.1.14` installed on my web server (`IIS 10`). Now I have `PHP 7.2`. The problem is that when `Warning` error appears script stops (nothing else except warning message on a screen) but previously if `warning` error then script continue until the end. I don't know which parameter allows me to see errors and continue script?

Comment: Warning does not suppress script execution even on 7.2, unless, that warning leads to a fatal further down the line. That's about as good as a guess I have.

Comment: I have a simple `PHP Warning:  include(C:\....\config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory ` error and there is nothing else with php `7.2.5` but when i change back to `7.1.14` then i can see this error and other script results after

Comment: I can only assume that the config is important enough that the script fails(?).

Comment: @Andrew but why it's fails only with 7.2 but not with 7.1?

Comment: Again, I'm guesstimating here, probably something that was working in 7.1 no longer works in 7.2. And I'm talking here about some function or whatever. This is a gigantic guess on my part so take everything with a mountain of salt.

Comment: Isn't it better to just fix the warnings? Seems like a better use of your time than spending time trying to make PHP run with them.

Comment: Where do you "see errors"? (hint: the correct answer is not in your browser). How do you know the script stops executing?

Comment: @symcbean I have a code inside `try... catch...finally` and with `7.1` i can see `finally` part but with `7.2` i can't

Comment: Again, where do you "see errors"?